Catalog of integral symmetric matrices
Let $g$ be an integral symmetric matrix (perhaps with even diagonal components), and define an equivalence relation $g\sim g'$ if $g=Ug'U^T$ with $U$ a unimodular integral matrix.
For fixed $\det g$ (and size), there are finitely many equivalence classes. I am looking for a catalog of representatives for all classes, for small values of $\det g$. In a previous laptop I had a bookmark of a webpage with precisely this, but now I cannot find it anymore. Any help is appreciated.
Of course this is equivalent to a catalog of integer (possibly even) lattices, with $g$ the Gram matrix thereof. I am aware of http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/, unfortunately this webpage does not seem  to give the full list (e.g., in dimension 2 they only list A2 and D2).
I would also be happy with a catalog for representatives up to stable equivalence rather than just congruence.

x-posted from math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4965038

What success did you have with Nipp's tables in dimensions 4,5   and Schiemann's in dimension 3? with even diagonal in the Gram matrix, http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Brandt_2.html  Then Nipp  4:  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/nipp.html   and 5: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/nipp5.html  One form per line, easy enough to read  the ordered tuple, create the indicated Gram matrix, do whatever
